# Serializable в java

Tags: java, serializable

Привет! У меня есть вопрос по Java. Почему модификатор типу `transient` в примере не обнуляет `String a = null`.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializeDog implements Serializable {
    private String a;
    private transient String b;
    public SerializeDog(String aa,String bb) {
        a = "Not announced as transient : " + aa;
        b = "Announced as transient : " + bb;
    }
    public String toString(){return a + "\n" + b;}
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        stream.defaultWriteObject();
        stream.writeObject(b);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
    stream.defaultReadObject();
    b = (String)stream.readObject();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
    SerializeDog sd = new SerializeDog("paper 1", "paper 2");

    System.out.println("before : " + sd);

    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("File"));
    o.writeObject(sd);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("File"));
    SerializeDog sd2 = (SerializeDog)in.readObject();
    System.out.println("after : " + sd2);
    }

}
```

и результат вот:

```
before : Not announced as transient : paper 1
Announced as transient : paper 2
after : Not announced as transient : paper 1
Announced as transient : paper 2
```

Comment: Во-первых, `transient` написан у `b`, ну а во-вторых, вы сами сохраняете значение из `b` и потом сами же его вычитываете. Если просто использовать методы записи и чтения по умолчанию - то данное поле будет игнорироваться и после десериализации вы увидите в нем `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поля, которые помечены ключевым словом `transient` не сериализуются в том случае, если используеся метод записи по умолчанию. Если мы заглянем в исходный код класса `ObjectStreamClass` и найдём метод `getDefaultSerialFields`, который возвращает набор полей класса для сериализации, то увидим, что в нём игнорируются статические поля и поля, помеченные как `transient`.

Однако вы сами записываете и читаете значение из поля `b` в собственных реализациях методов `writeObject` и `readObject` - в этом случае ключевое слово `transient` никак не учитывается.